# Group Settings Using PowerShell

Tags: permissions, groups, settings

I have been tasked with finding our site's SharePoint groups that have the Group Setting "Who can view the membership of the group?" set to Group Members. Is there a search feature or PowerShell command that can provide this?

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```
$site = Get-SPSite("http://siteurl");

foreach($subweb in $site.AllWebs){
    foreach($group in $subweb.Groups)
    {           
        if($group.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership -eq $true)
            write-host $group.Name
    }
    $subweb.Dispose();
}

$site.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Small update - cool script but it needs the statement block operators before and after the write-host command in the if statement:

```
$site = Get-SPSite("http://siteurl");

foreach($subweb in $site.AllWebs){
    foreach($group in $subweb.Groups)
    {           
        if($group.OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership -eq $true)
            {
             write-host $group.Name
            }
    }
    $subweb.Dispose();
}

$site.Dispose();
```